# how many instances did a command affect?

Tags: sed

Is there a way when using `sed` from the cli to return how many lines were affected, or better yet how many instances were affected by a command that might have multiple affects per line if the global param is used? Pretty much, for me, that would mean how many substitutions were made.

I guess one could output to a new file and then run a `diff` on the two files afterward, but my need to know how many instances a command affects is not that great to do that. I just wondered if there might be a feature native to `sed` that can be employed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, **sed** has no native feature to manipulate variables (e.g. to increase an internal counter). Definitely, that is one of the features brought by **awk** that were lacking in **sed**. So my advice would be that you switch to **awk**, and then you can easily use an **awk** script such as:

```
BEGIN { counter = 0 }
/mypattern/ { do-whatever-you-want; counter++ }
END { print counter }
```

Comment: Right, +1. You dont need the BEGIN section, though, just change the END to `END { print counter+0 }` to make sure you get a digit output even if the variable never got incremented.

Comment: @EdMorton: thanks! You know, I never feel really 100% safe when using uninitialized variables in **awk**, kindof I wouldn't assume the script is guaranteed to work well in every implementation of **awk** and whatever the input stream you give it, so I prefer to go with this `BEGIN` safety feature...

Comment: That's fine but it IS guaranteed to work in every implementation. It must because fundamental to awk is the concept of variables all being of type "numeric string" until they are first used and as such BEFORE they are first used they must have some value and that value is guaranteed to be "zero or null". If you were to init awk variables in general what would you init them to since there is no value of "zero or null" that you could use on the right side of the `=` sign? Since you cannot generally init awk variables without breaking the paradigm, awk MUST provide an initial value for them.

Comment: although not a sed solution, accepting the answer b/c it does not require the creation of another file to track changes. I really do gotta just sit down some day/week and learn awk.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for a `sed` solution.  Here is a pure `sed` approach that does *some* of what you want:

```
sed 's/old/new/;t change;b;:change w changes'
```

After executing this, the changed lines, if any, are written to the file `changes`.

How it works:

- `s/old/new/;`

  Replace this with whatever substitution you want to do.
- `t change;`

  This tells `sed` to jump to the label `change` if the preceding `s` command made any changes.
- `b;`

  If the preceding jump did not happen, then this `b` command is executed which ends the processing of this line.
- `:change w changes`

  This tells `sed` to write the current line, as changed by your `s` command, to the file `changes`.

#### The Next Step

The next step here would be to *count* the changes.  To this end, [`sed` can do arithmetic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed) but it is not for the faint of heart.

#### OSX

As I recall, the version of `sed` on Mac OSX does not support chaining commands together with semicolons.  Instead, try:

```
sed -e 's/old/new/' -e 't change' -e b -e ':change w changes'
```